# How to link a static library to an executable using CMake

Tags: cmake

In CMake, we use TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES() to link a shared library to an library/executable.

```
For example:
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ExecutableName xxx)
   where ExecutableName - is the name of executable
         xxx - is the library name.
```

As of my understanding CMake searches for "libxxx.so" at the paths mentioned in LINK_DIRECTORIES() macro.
But if I have a third party library with name "libxxx.a" then how do I link the library to the executable using CMake.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You should always try to give either full paths or CMake targets to target_link_libraries.

Since you do not seem to build the dependency as part of the CMake project, the only way to obtain a CMake target to link against, is to create an imported target. This is usually quite tedious to do manuall, so unless the dependency already provides a config file with an imported target, you probably do not want to go down that road. Imported targets are the most convenient to use, but only if you can get CMake to write the for you.

So, absolute paths it is then. You obviously would not want to hardcode absolute library paths in your CMakeLists. As pointed out in your question, the desired behavior is that you specify just the name of a library and CMake should be able to figure out its location automatically. This is exactly what [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/find_library.html) does for you.

To link against a library `xxx`, you would do something like this:

```
find_library(LIB_LOCATION xxx)
target_link_libraries(ExecutableName ${LIB_LOCATION})
```

Note that `find_library` provides a plethora of options to further specify where to look for the requested library. Get rid of your existing `link_directories` call and add the respective paths as hints to `find_library` instead.

This approach is both more flexible when porting your CMake code to other platforms and more easy to debug if something goes wrong than your initial approach.

Comment: How to tell find_library to look for static lib?  find_library(CURL_LIBRARY_LIB_LOCATION curl) still prints the path '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so'.

Comment: @BTRNaidu In that case you should [give the full name of the library, including the `.a`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_library.html). Note that you can give more than one name to search for to `find_library`. So the final command would look something like: `find_library(l NAMES libcurl.a curl)`. I agree that this is not the prettiest solution, but it's currently the only way to tell CMake which one to take if you have both static and dynamic versions lying around.

Answer (score 2):

Just specifying the library filename should work:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ExecutableName libxxx.a)
```

and

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ExecutableName xxx)
```

actually should work too as that would not look for the .so but for a libxxx.a file in the search paths.