# Undefined reference

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

iam trying to port an arduino project to esp-idf while porting im getting an error something like given below

> [1/6] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
> [1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.5\workspace\GAZZELE_MINI\build\bootloader\esp-idf\esptool_py && C:\Espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.11_env\Scripts\python.exe C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x1000 C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin"
> Bootloader binary size 0x63f0 bytes. 0xc10 bytes (11%) free.
> [2/4] Linking CXX executable GAZZELE_MINI.elf
> FAILED: GAZZELE_MINI.elf
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  @CMakeFiles\GAZZELE_MINI.elf.rsp -o GAZZELE_MINI.elf  && cd ."
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj):(.literal.initCameraSettings+0x18): undefined reference to `esp_camera_init' c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj):(.literal.initCameraSettings+0x1c): undefined reference to` esp_camera_sensor_get'
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj):(.literal.capturePhotoSaveSpiffs+0x38): undefined reference to `esp_camera_fb_get' c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj):(.literal.capturePhotoSaveSpiffs+0x40): undefined reference to` esp_camera_fb_return'
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj): in function `initCameraSettings': C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/main/DriverModules/CamDrivers/Camera_Settings.cpp:56: undefined reference to` esp_camera_init'
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/main/DriverModules/CamDrivers/Camera_Settings.cpp:56: undefined reference to `esp_camera_sensor_get' c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/main/DriverModules/CamDrivers/Camera_Settings.cpp:72: undefined reference to` esp_camera_sensor_get'
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(Camera_Settings.cpp.obj): in function `capturePhotoSaveSpiffs': C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/main/DriverModules/CamDrivers/Camera_Settings.cpp:194: undefined reference to` esp_camera_fb_get'
> c:/espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.5/workspace/GAZZELE_MINI/main/DriverModules/CamDrivers/Camera_Settings.cpp:209: undefined reference to `esp_camera_fb_return'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

i have also checked cmake everything is fine i donno how to solve this error can anyone help me with this

i have tried looking through cmake and iam using esp-idf as vscode extension

Comment: if you need to review the code i can sent you privately just lemme know if anyone need how i arrived to this error

Answer (score 0):

This error output means that your linker couldn't find the library that contains object code of `esp_camera_init`, `esp_camera_fb_get`, etc.

So you need to add corresponding static library to your app. How to do this could be found here: [How to link a static library to an executable using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536435/how-to-link-a-static-library-to-an-executable-using-cmake), for example

Comment: yeah actually in cmake i have'nt added some source file

https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/issues/565

you can follow above link i clearly stated problem I'm facing now